# Actions must be plain objects Error In React and Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to set the message on a notification for a user if they vote for an item.

This is the error i'm getting and it's happening when i click the buttong and evoke my voteHandler function.

```
×
Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.
```

This is the function and the error message is highlighting the line where i call the setNotification function.

```
 const voteHandler = anecdote => {
    props.addVote(anecdote);
    const notification = `You voted for ${anecdote.content}`;
    props.setNotification(notification, 5);
  };
```

This is my notification reducer:

```
const initialState = null;

const notificationReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET_NOTIFICATION":
      state = action.data;
      return state;
    case "REMOVE_NOTIFICATION":
      return initialState;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export const setNotification = (content, seconds) => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({
      type: "SET_NOTIFICATION",
      content
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
      dispatch({
        type: "REMOVE_NOTIFICATION"
      });
    }, seconds * 1000);
  };
};

export const removeNotification = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({
      type: "REMOVE_NOTIFICATION",
      notification: null
    });
  };
};

export default notificationReducer;
```

I've been experimenting with this and the notification message will appear if I only use this function for setNotification, thus it looks like maybe there is an issue with how i'm calling the setTimeout call?

```
export const setNotification = (content, seconds) => {
  return {
    type: "SET_NOTIFICATION",
    data: content
  };
};
```

I'm still learning Redux so maybe this is an obvious mistake, but i'm just not certain.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
export const setNotification = (content, seconds) => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({
      type: "SET_NOTIFICATION",
      content
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
      dispatch({
        type: "REMOVE_NOTIFICATION"
      });
    }, seconds * 1000);
  };
};
```

The problem should be coming from the above code. You will need to install Redux-Thunk if you wished to `dispatch` multiple `object` from your redux action.

```js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers/index';

// Note: this API requires redux@>=3.1.0
const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
```